# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObjectId'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

im trying to simply add a role to roles array in a found user
from User.findOne
so i found the user

and then i try to push body string to roles array in User

```
import { Router } from "express";

import _ from "underscore";
import { User } from "../db/models/user.js";
import { Role } from "../db/models/role.js";
import { roleAddValidate } from "../middleware/roles/roleAdd.js";

const router = Router();

//api/auth/signup
router.post("/add", roleAddValidate, async (req, res) => {
  const body = _.pick(req.body, "username", "role");

  let user = await await User.findOne({ username: body.username });
  let role = await Role.findOne({ name: body.role });

  //before saving the user:
  try {
    //for each user -> save the role id of user
    user.roles.push(role._id);

    await user.save();
    return res.json({
      message: `Role ${body.role} added to ${body.username}`,
      id: user._id,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Server DB Error", error: e });
  }
});

export { router as roleRouter };
```

so the probem is :

```
 user.roles.push(role._id);
```

if i remove it everything is ok but it dosent add the role to role Array

any ideas?
thanks!

i try to add role to role Array in User

Comment: are you using mongodb?

Comment: Can you share the type definitions for `User` and `ObjectId`?